# Nesting view based NSTableViews in xib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to nest one NSTableView inside another view based tableview in my xib. When I do so, I get the following build error (when trying to compile the xib):

`An instance of NSTableColumn with object ID jRp-dg-jOe did not archive its child (NSTableCellView) with an object of ID y8a-qz-ChK`

Has anybody seen this, or know how to fix it?

I assume I could just create another xib for the NSTableCellView, and hook it up to the parent NSTableView using

`NSNib *cellNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyCellContainingAnNSTableView" bundle:nil];
[parentTable registerNib:cellNib forIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];`

but that's a little more annoying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so it seems like nobody has any solutions for this...

After a long time looking, it seems that Interface Builder is just incapable of archiving nested NSTableViews. My solution was to create a new `.xib` containing an `NSTableCellView` and referencing that from the original `NSTableView`. Here's how to do it:

- Create a new NSTableCellView in a separate `.xib`. Call it something like `SchemeCell.xib`
- Add an `NSTableViewDelegate` to your code, and set it as the delegate for your main (parent) tableview.
- Add in the method:

  ```
  - (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
               NSNib *cellNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"SchemeCell" bundle:nil];
               [self.schemeTableView registerNib:cellNib forIdentifier:@"SchemeCell"];
        });
        return [self.schemeTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"SchemeCell" owner:self];
   }
  ```

And away you go! Now the main disadvantage to this is that you can no longer use Interface Builder to hook up items from the `SchemeCell` to the parent `NSTableView` (since they are now both in separate `.xibs`, but it's not the end of the world, because you can do all of this within the code of course.

Comment: Sticking the registerNib inside a `dispatch_once` is probably a bad idea. If a second instance of schemaTableView is ever allocated, it will never have `registerNib` called on it.